If $f$ is smooth and compactly supported, does it mean that $-\Delta + f$ is self-adjoint?
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be open and $f \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ be a smooth, compactly supported real-valued function. Let $K$ be a compact set such that $\text{supp} f \subset K$. Assume that $f >0$ pointwise almost everywhere. If $\psi$ belongs to the Sobolev space $H^{2}(\Omega)$, then:
$$\|f\psi\|^{2}_{L^{2}} =\int_{\Omega}f^{2}(x)|\psi(x)|^{2} \le \sup_{x\in K}f^{2}(x)\int_{\Omega}|\psi(x)|^{2}.$$
Hence, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that:
$$\|f\psi\|_{L^{2}} \le C\|\psi\| \tag{1}\label{1}$$.
My question is the following. Consider the Laplacian $-\Delta$ on $\Omega$ with periodic boundary conditions. Its natural domain of definition is $H^{2}(\Omega)$. From the above analysis, it seems that I can simply add any term of the form $a\|\Delta \psi\|_{L^{2}}$, $a\ge 0$, on the right hand side of (\ref{1}), so to obtain:
$$\|f\psi\|_{L^{2}} \le C\|\psi\| + a\|\Delta\psi\|.$$
Choosing $a<1$, does this imply that $-\Delta+f$ is self-adjoint on $H^{2}(\Omega)$ by Kato-Rellich Theorem? On one hand, I don't see anything wrong with the proof, but on the other hand it is very strange to be able to add $a\|\Delta \psi\|$ on the right side of (\ref{1}) for every $a \ge 0$, just because it is positive, and choose $a<1$ to get check the Kato-Rellich condition for free. Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

Do you mean that $\Omega$ is a rectangle? I cannot understand "periodic boundary conditions" otherwise.

Ops! Yes, sure! I should have made it clear. Thanks!
